# WordPress slow pages/post, hangs and white text

Tags: pages, errors

I've updated to WP version 4.1.

I can't figure out what went wrong, I didn't change or updated plugins.

The only thing I can think of is that I inserted 5000 pages with `wp_insert_post`. (I don't often edit pages).

I insert all those pages as "normal" pages.

> /wp-admin/post.php?post=15195&action=edit Failed to load resource: the
> server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: switchEditors is not defined (after clicking text)

Comment: Activate the Debug mode of WordPress and see  error message, also it is helpful to deactivated all plugins and use the default theme.

Comment: I concur with @bueltge. You need to activate debugging, either to a log or the screen. A WSOD is typically a fatal PHP error so the log file is a map of what went wrong.

Comment: Website is now running with lots of traffic because of 31 december. I will come back 1 januari with those reports

Comment: thanks found it bad plugin. how to remove this topic? somehow i missed an updated plugin